# Haxe flixel-addons error "Unknown identifier : WALL"

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel-addons/2,11,0/flixel/addons/display/FlxExtendedSprite.hx:11:
> characters 8-37 : Type not found : flixel.util.FlxDirectionFlags
> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel-addons/2,11,0/flixel/addons/display/FlxExtendedSprite.hx:484:
> characters 21-25 : Unknown identifier : WALL
> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel-addons/2,11,0/flixel/addons/display/FlxExtendedSprite.hx:504:
> characters 21-25 : Unknown identifier : WALL
> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel-addons/2,11,0/flixel/addons/display/FlxExtendedSprite.hx:530:
> characters 21-28 : Unknown identifier : CEILING
> C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/flixel-addons/2,11,0/flixel/addons/display/FlxExtendedSprite.hx:550:
> characters 21-26 : Unknown identifier : FLOOR

Can someone help me?

Comment: The real error is the first line: `Type not found : flixel.util.FlxDirectionFlags `
That class is included into the main `flixel` lib; it is correctly installed & included in Project.xml?

Comment: Could you add the output of the command `haxelib list` too?

Comment: I tried using previous version of haxe, now it works fine, thanks for your answer anyway.